# How can I display the answer choices for my survey?

Tags: javascript, html, object, survey

so I've coded a questionnaire/survey for my website but for some reason when a user clicks start questionnaire the questions show but the choices aren't displayed. I'm really confused as to why this isn't working I would really appreciate if anyone can help me solve my problem, thank you!

Here's a link to my IDE as I figured it would be easier to go through it to identify any mistakes I'm making: https://repl.it/@AS11RA/Forest-Firefighters-Website#index.html

Here's the start questionnaire.js file:

```
function buttonClicked(button) {
  button.style.visibility = "hidden";
  startSurvey();
  console.log("Survey started.");
}

function startSurvey() {

  var i;
  var j;
  var k;
  for (i = 0; i < ourQuestions.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += '<form id="question">Q' + (i + 1) + ': ' + ourQuestions[i].question;

    for (j = 0; j < ourQuestions[i].answers.length; j++) {
      document.forms[i].innerHTML += '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="' + ourQuestions[i].answers[j] + '" id="value4" type="checkbox" />' + ourQuestions[i].answers[j] + '<br/>';
    }
    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += '</form><br/><br/>';
  }

  document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += '<button class="button" onclick="solveQuiz()">Solve Quiz</button>';

}

var ourQuestions = [{
    question: 'While naturally occurring wildfires can benefit ecosystems, unnatural blazes started by uncaring and negligent humans can do great harm and cause many deaths. What percentage of wildfires do you think are started by humans?',
    answers: {
      a: '10-15%',
      b: '85-90%',
      c: '45-50%',
      d: '25-30%'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b'
  },
  {
    question: 'If you have lit a campfire before, how did you extinguish it?',
    answers: {
      a: 'I did not extinguish it and waited for it to die on its own',
      b: 'I extinguished the campfire with a bucket of water and made sure it was fully extinguished.',
      c: 'I have never lit a campfire before.',
      d: 'uhhh'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b'
  },
  {
    question: 'What are the two most common reasons that forest fires start?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Lightning and human negligence',
      b: 'Spontaneous combustion and erosion',
      c: 'Animals igniting flames and overcrowded bushlands',
      d: 'Strong Wind Patterns'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'What time of the year do most forest fires occur?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Summer',
      b: 'Spring',
      c: 'Fall',
      d: 'Winter'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'How fast do you think forest fires spread?',
    answers: {
      a: '10.8 km/h',
      b: '6.4 km/h',
      c: '22.2 km/h',
      d: '3.2 km/h'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'What do forest fires need in order to burn?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Water',
      b: 'High humidity',
      c: 'Fuel',
      d: 'Clear weather'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c'
  },
  {
    question: 'What is one of the main toxic gases present in forest fire smoke?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Osmium tetroxide',
      b: 'Disulfur decafluoride',
      c: 'Tungsten hexafluoride ',
      d: 'carbon monoxide'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'd'
  },
  {
    question: 'What natural disasters could be caused as a consequence of a destructive forest fire?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Erosion, flash flooding and landslides',
      b: 'Tornadoes',
      c: 'Snow',
      d: 'Tsunami and earthquakes'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'What major factor determines a forest fire’s behaviour?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Amount of water vapour in air',
      b: 'Density of Forests',
      c: 'Wind',
      d: 'Hours of sunlight'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c'
  },
  {
    question: 'What 3 things are needed to start a fire?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Matches, oxygen, wood',
      b: 'Air and sunlight',
      c: 'Fuel, heat, oxygen',
      d: 'Fuel, oxygen, wood'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c'
  },
  {
    question: 'Which one of these is NOT a type of forest fire?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Crown',
      b: 'Firework',
      c: 'Surface',
      d: 'Ground '
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b'
  },
  {
    question: 'What was the cause of the Amazon forest fires in 2019?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Deforestation for agriculture usage',
      b: 'Fireworks',
      c: 'Unattended campfire',
      d: 'Arson'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'Which one of these names are NOT an alternate name for forest fires?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Wildfires',
      b: 'Shrub fires',
      c: 'Natural fireworks',
      d: 'Brushfires '
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c'
  },
  {
    question: 'How many forest fires occurred in 2019?',
    answers: {
      a: '25 653',
      b: '50 477',
      c: '45 809',
      d: '89 431'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b'
  }
];



function solveSurvey() {
  var x;
  var txt = ' ';
  var i = 0;
  var correct = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
    x = document.forms[i];
    for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
      if (x[j].checked) {
        correctAnswer = ourQuestions[i].correctAnswer;
        if (x[j].value == ourQuestions[i].answers[correctAnswer]) {
          correct += 1;
        }
      }
    }
      document.forms[i].innerHTML += '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="' + ourQuestions[i].answers[j] + '" id="value4" type="radio" />' + ourQuestions[i].answers[j] + '<br/>';
  }
  document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += 'Correct answers: ' + correct;
  

}
```

Here's the questionnaire.HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Forest Firefighters: Questionnaire</title>
    <link href="survey style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="main style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="start questionnaire.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <!--────────────────Header───────────────-->
      <header>
          <nav> 
            <ul class="nav-bar"><div class="bg"></div>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link active" href="questionnaire.html">Questionnaire</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="learning more.html">Learning more</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Ways you can help</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
      </header>

    <main>
        <!--─────────────────Home────────────────-->
        <div id="home">
            <div class="filter"></div>

        <!--────questionnaire button─────-->        
        <button class="button" onclick="buttonClicked(this)">Start Questionnaire</button>
        <spacer></spacer>
        <div id="questions"></div>
        <spacer></spacer>
        <spacer></spacer>
        </div>
    
      
          <div class="citing">
        <a class="citing-link" href=questionnaire.html">Image Source: https://phys.org/news/2019-11-countries-forest.html</a>
      <div>      
      </main>  

    <!--─────────────────Footer────────────────-->
      <footer class="copyright">© 2020 Amber, Aatiqah, Selina</footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your answers don't display is because you are trying to loop through the answers like it is an array. However, answers is an object, not an array so you cannot really do things like using the answers.length property etc.

However, instead of converting your answers into an array, there is actually an easier way to deal with this. That is to use a **for...of** loop with **object.entries** on the ourQueuestions.answers object. By using the Object.entries(ourQuestions.answers) method you will be able to retrieve the answers in 'key' and 'value' pairs and easily use them in the loop without the classic for loop and i and j variables etc.

Also, you were referencing to the solveQuiz() method in the below codeblock, however, in your code the name of this method is actually solveSurvey() and not solveQuiz(). So I've changed that too in the below code:

```
document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML +=
    '<button class="button" onclick="solveSurvey()">Solve Quiz</button>';
}
```

Lastly, I would recommend that you read about the ES6 features from MDN docs, stuff like the **for...of** loop and **string literals** have been introduced in ES6 into Javascript back in 2015 and they will make your life way easier as a developer using JS :)

[MDN ES6 Features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla)

goodluck! You can directly use the code below and see that it successfully also displays answers on the UI.

```
function buttonClicked(button) {
  button.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  startSurvey();
  console.log('Survey started.');
}

function startSurvey() {
  var i;
  var j;
  var k;
  for (i = 0; i < ourQuestions.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML +=
      '<form id="question">Q' + (i + 1) + ': ' + ourQuestions[i].question;
    debugger;
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(ourQuestions[i].answers)) {
      document.forms[i].innerHTML +=
        '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="' +
        value +
        '" id="value4" type="checkbox" />' +
        `${key}: '${value}'`; //use a string literal, makes a dev's life very easy
      ('<br/>');
    }
    document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML += '</form><br/><br/>';
  }

  document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML +=
    '<button class="button" onclick="solveSurvey()">Solve Quiz</button>';
}

var ourQuestions = [
  {
    question:
      'While naturally occurring wildfires can benefit ecosystems, unnatural blazes started by uncaring and negligent humans can do great harm and cause many deaths. What percentage of wildfires do you think are started by humans?',
    answers: {
      a: '10-15%',
      b: '85-90%',
      c: '45-50%',
      d: '25-30%',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b',
  },
  {
    question: 'If you have lit a campfire before, how did you extinguish it?',
    answers: {
      a: 'I did not extinguish it and waited for it to die on its own',
      b:
        'I extinguished the campfire with a bucket of water and made sure it was fully extinguished.',
      c: 'I have never lit a campfire before.',
      d: 'uhhh',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b',
  },
  {
    question: 'What are the two most common reasons that forest fires start?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Lightning and human negligence',
      b: 'Spontaneous combustion and erosion',
      c: 'Animals igniting flames and overcrowded bushlands',
      d: 'Strong Wind Patterns',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a',
  },
  {
    question: 'What time of the year do most forest fires occur?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Summer',
      b: 'Spring',
      c: 'Fall',
      d: 'Winter',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a',
  },
  {
    question: 'How fast do you think forest fires spread?',
    answers: {
      a: '10.8 km/h',
      b: '6.4 km/h',
      c: '22.2 km/h',
      d: '3.2 km/h',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a',
  },
  {
    question: 'What do forest fires need in order to burn?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Water',
      b: 'High humidity',
      c: 'Fuel',
      d: 'Clear weather',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c',
  },
  {
    question:
      'What is one of the main toxic gases present in forest fire smoke?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Osmium tetroxide',
      b: 'Disulfur decafluoride',
      c: 'Tungsten hexafluoride ',
      d: 'carbon monoxide',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'd',
  },
  {
    question:
      'What natural disasters could be caused as a consequence of a destructive forest fire?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Erosion, flash flooding and landslides',
      b: 'Tornadoes',
      c: 'Snow',
      d: 'Tsunami and earthquakes',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a',
  },
  {
    question: 'What major factor determines a forest fire’s behaviour?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Amount of water vapour in air',
      b: 'Density of Forests',
      c: 'Wind',
      d: 'Hours of sunlight',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c',
  },
  {
    question: 'What 3 things are needed to start a fire?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Matches, oxygen, wood',
      b: 'Air and sunlight',
      c: 'Fuel, heat, oxygen',
      d: 'Fuel, oxygen, wood',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c',
  },
  {
    question: 'Which one of these is NOT a type of forest fire?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Crown',
      b: 'Firework',
      c: 'Surface',
      d: 'Ground ',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b',
  },
  {
    question: 'What was the cause of the Amazon forest fires in 2019?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Deforestation for agriculture usage',
      b: 'Fireworks',
      c: 'Unattended campfire',
      d: 'Arson',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a',
  },
  {
    question:
      'Which one of these names are NOT an alternate name for forest fires?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Wildfires',
      b: 'Shrub fires',
      c: 'Natural fireworks',
      d: 'Brushfires ',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c',
  },
  {
    question: 'How many forest fires occurred in 2019?',
    answers: {
      a: '25 653',
      b: '50 477',
      c: '45 809',
      d: '89 431',
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b',
  },
];

function solveSurvey() {
  var x;
  var txt = ' ';
  var i = 0;
  var correct = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
    x = document.forms[i];
    for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
      if (x[j].checked) {
        correctAnswer = ourQuestions[i].correctAnswer;
        if (x[j].value == ourQuestions[i].answers[correctAnswer]) {
          correct += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    document.forms[i].innerHTML +=
      '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="' +
      ourQuestions[i].answers[j] +
      '" id="value4" type="radio" />' +
      ourQuestions[i].answers[j] +
      '<br/>';
  }
  document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML +=
    'Correct answers: ' + correct;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you sosos much I truly, really appreciate it a lot!! @Link

Comment: also when a user is done the questionnaire how can I give them their final result?

Comment: You will need to implement that functionality in the solveSurvey method which is the handler function for the button click event.

Comment: I thought I already implemented it, is there something I'm doing wrong with that code?

Comment: If by 'giving a user their result' you mean to display their score, then you just need to display the 'correct' variable on the UI. :)

Comment: oh ok because right now it just shows like "you got 10 answers correct on the side beside the solve survey button" I was wondering how I can make the results appear on a separate page?

Comment: sorry the new button's name is now "Submit Questionnaire"

Comment: If you want to show it in a different page, you can either redirect user to a different html or just use css hidden property and add it to the existing <main> and hide the entire content and have a separate main tag which is hidden by default and show it when you submit the questionnaire. Within this main you can have html like it is a different page altogether.

Comment: ok thank you, I want to be able to do the second part. Is there a way you can show me how to do it with my code, if you can't its totally fine thank you!

Comment: Hope this helps: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: sorry just another question, when I click submit questionnaire it shows an undefined option under each question how can I get rid of it?

Comment: ourQuestions[i].answers[j] -- It's because of this. You need to do this instead in the end: ourQuestions{i].correctAnswer;

Comment: wait I'm confused where would I add and how cuz I have two lines of code that say that

Answer (score 0):

I ran it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raddevus/jbec837y/8/) and got the following error:

> "ReferenceError: buttonClicked is not defined"

You have some formatting issues in your code, I believe.
I moved your button up in the page and it started working.  Check out the fiddle.

```
  <body >
  <button class="button" onclick="buttonClicked(this)">Start Questionnaire</button>
```

I also removed your JavaScript, except for the `buttonClick` function.

You need to add your code in until it works.

Here's an edited fiddle that shows your questions:

https://jsfiddle.net/raddevus/jbec837y/10/

Comment: ^ forgot to tag u

Comment: @28space_junkiee  You can copy the code in my second fiddle link (updated answer) and you'll be on your way. The 2nd one shows your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In ourQuestions you created answers as object like below

```
answers: {
      a: '10-15%',
      b: '85-90%',
      c: '45-50%',
      d: '25-30%'
}
```

but in code you trying to get length of it

```
for (j = 0; j < ourQuestions[i].answers.length; j++)
```

try changing it to array, and you should change logic to get correct answer
and one more thing you using checkbox to select answer instead you should use radio group as you have only one correct answer